# Best way to show progress of some process on view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have no idea how to do that, but I think it is possible. What I want to do is show progress of some process (loop) to my view.

I'm using C# ASP.NET MVC3/RAZOR

Code example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); // Simulate...
    }

    return View();
}
```

And in my view I just want to make simple text like `44/100`.

Is it possible, and if it is then what would be the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Your view won't return until the loop is complete, so there is no way to return anything. You would need to run the work request and the progress request from different ajax requests or something. Long running processes shouldn't run on your web server anyway BTW.

Comment: Yea but can't you simulate something with another action that returns some partial view using JS?

Comment: Have you considered using just an animated gif that you can hide once the process finishes? Might be worth considering if the time needed to complete this is not too long. Showing progress is doable but very involved if it is to be accurate.
http://www.andrewdavidson.com/articles/spinning-wait-icons/

Comment: @santiagoIT Haha, sure. But that would be easy, but not really what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BNL's comment above is correct.

1. Start your task in a different thread using the Task Parallel library. Update task progress within this task.
2. Write an action method that polls the progress every few seconds using ajax.
3. Update your UI based on progress.

How do you keep track of progress?

1. Create a task identifier in a database (say a table with 2 columns: a guid and a progress value).
2. Return the task identifier value from the action method.
3. Send the task identifier in your ajax call so you can tell the server to give you the progress of the specified task.

And yes, it's worth repeating: don't run long tasks in the web server thread. Run a windows service and let it run the tasks for you.

Comment: Do not create threads on a web server. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Also checkout AsyncController http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx